# How can we allow user to set a cron JOB from frontend in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, cron, scheduling, cron-task

I have a setting section in my laravel application. In this section I have a setting for defining a sync time. So the user can set their preferred time for sync data from laravel application to a third party CRM(Salesforce).

For now, I am storing a sync time into Database table. Now I want to run a cron JOB at that time for a particular user.

I have already created a cron job script and the cron job script is working fine. I am able to test cron job manually I just need to automate it with user setting(Preferred time).
My Cron JOB URL https://my-domain.org/cronjob?user_id=101

I tried to use laravel [scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling) but this not fulfillig my requirement.

Is there any other better solution available at laravel?

Comment: Why does `scheduling` not work for you?

Comment: Because we didn't have a predefined time, we are allowing a user to set their own time for sync. Also each time we run cron job it sync 20 records and we may have more than 20 records. SO we need to run run cron job untill all recods not synced  but sync starts on the time that user specify.

Comment: This can be done with scheduling. Set the scheduler to run every minute, and within your `command`, check the DB, and determine which job(s) to execute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is some information missing but I try to assume a few things to hopefully propose a working solution using the Laravel scheduler.

---

Assuming you store the time at which the CRON runs in the database as `01:00` for 1 o'clock in the night you could do the following:

```php
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    User::query()->whereNotNull('cron_time')->each(function (User $user) use ($schedule) {
        $schedule->command('app:import', ['user_id' => $user->id])
                 ->withoutOverlapping() // prevents running the same command (+ parameters) twice at the same time, should only be a problem if the command can run > 24 hours, but still a safe thing to do
                 ->dailyAt($user->cron_time);
    });
}
```

- I dreamed up that you stored the information on the User model
- That you used a flag in the database called `cron_time` which contains the `01:00` or is `null` if the cron is disabled
- The cron needs to run daily at that user supplied time
- The import command is called `app:import` and is a console command that accept a `user_id` argument with the user id to run the import for

This might help you adapt the above to how it's structured in you own app.

---

If you want to use queued jobs to execute the imports you could also create the `app:import` CLI command to just dispatch that job instead of actually running the import. Depending on the amount of imports it might be a good idea to prevent long running scheduler commands and have the ability to retry and have a timeout.

---

Another option could also be to have a daily scheduled command that dispatches jobs to the queue scheduled to run at a specific time (which does not work with the SES driver). For more about that see: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#delayed-dispatching.

Comment: 1. What about if more than one user have same time `01:00`? Will the cron job run for every user?
2. We also need to run the same cron job multiple time, untill all data not sync. In a single run script will sync 20 records and if we have more than 20 records than we need to run cron job multiple times?

Comment: 1. Yes. It would run for every user since it registeres a scheduled job for every user. However reading your second question You should modify the script to not be killed after the first 20 but implement some kind of loop to keep importing until all records are processed before exiting. You could also as mentioned fire a queue job for the import and fire a new queue job from there to keep processing more records.

Comment: Thanks Alex for the help. I have created a command and trying to run comand via `php artisan schedule:run` but there is no cron setup.

Result of commnad: `No scheduled commands are ready to run.`

My code is `SyncSetting::query()->whereNotNull('run_cron_at')->each(function (SyncSetting $setting) use ($schedule) {
            $schedule->command('orders:sync', ['user' => $setting->user_id])
                     ->withoutOverlapping() 
                     ->dailyAt($setting->run_cron_at);
        });`

Comment: My cron comand signature is `protected $signature = 'orders:sync {user}';`

Comment: That just means that currently there is no command to run. You do need to run it at exactly the time as stated in the database, that's the point ofcourse :) Did you try that?